# chromedriver azuredops pipeline failure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines

Iam trying to run a selenium test in azure pipeline, the test works fine in my local machine with:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_exe= ChromeDriverManager()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_exe.install(), options=options)
```

but when i run the same in the pipeline it fails with the following error.

```
E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
E         (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
E         (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.11/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242: WebDriverException
---------------------------- Captured stdout setup -----------------------------
 
---------------------------- Captured stderr setup -----------------------------
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 84.0.4147
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 84.0.4147
[WDM] - There is no [linux64] chromedriver for browser 84.0.4147 in cache
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 84.0.4147
[WDM] - Trying to download new driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[WDM] - Driver has been saved in cache [/home/vsts/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/84.0.4147.30]
```

manually i go to that path it says: No such object: chromedriver/84.0.4147.30
but if i query using [link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)
it gives the same version number

Answer (score 0):

> chromedriver azuredops pipeline failure

According to the error message, it seems the Chrome browser is not installed at the default location within your system.

For the `Linux` systems, the ChromeDriver expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary.

If you are using a Chrome executable in a non-standard location you can try to override the Chrome binary location as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\path\\to\\chrome.exe"    #chrome binary location specified here
options.add_argument("--start-maximized") #open Browser in maximized mode
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") #bypass OS security model
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage") #overcome limited resource problems
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801158/chromedriver-is-assuming-that-chrome-has-crashed-when-passing-profile-arguments) for some details.

Comment: Ok bit since, this is an .exe how do i set the path for linux binary for chrome and take that when it is running in a Linux pipeline and take this binary only if it is running in the local machine?